# VBA - categorizing info correctly into columns in different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

this is an issue I am faced with.

Sheet 1 contains info of ~300 rows of data of individuals, with their names in Column A, their qualifications such as "Bachelor's Degree" or "Master's Degree" in Column B, graduation date in Column C.

These individuals can have up to 4 different types of qualifications eg. Bachelor's Degree 1 in Column B, graduation date 2 in Column C, Master's Degree 2 in Column D, graduation date 2 in Column E etc.

Sheet 2 contains columns named "Bachelor's degree 1", "Bachelor's degree 2", "Master's degree 1", and "Master's degree 2", along with their respective graduation dates.

My question is, how do I write a VBA script that automatically sorts the data in Sheet 1 into the right columns in Sheet 2, alongside their respective graduation dates?

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is best solved using if statements.

b `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!B2)),Sheet1!B2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!D2)),Sheet1!D2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!F2)),Sheet1!F2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!H2)),Sheet1!H2,""))))`

c `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!B2)),Sheet1!C2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!D2)),Sheet1!E2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!F2)),Sheet1!G2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!H2)),Sheet1!I2,""))))`

d `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!B2)),Sheet1!B2<>B2),Sheet1!B2,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!D2)),Sheet1!D2<>B2),Sheet1!D2,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!F2)),Sheet1!F2<>B2),Sheet1!F2,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!H2)),Sheet1!H2<>B2),Sheet1!H2,""))))`

e `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!B2)),Sheet1!B2<>B2),Sheet1!C2,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!D2)),Sheet1!D2<>B2),Sheet1!E2,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!F2)),Sheet1!F2<>B2),Sheet1!G2,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bachelor",Sheet1!H2)),Sheet1!H2<>B2),Sheet1!I2,""))))`

then your next columns will be the same thing just with the word master instead of bachelor.

[image]